# Regex substring if backward and forward slash "\/"

Tags: regex, oracle, substr

What's the correct RegEx syntax for separating on a backward and forward slash?

For Oracle I have tried:

string

```
word1\/word2\/word3

regexp_substr(string, '[^"\\/"]+', 1, 1) first
```

but it does not work correctly

Comment: What's the desired output for the given input ?

Comment: Desired output would be first: word1

Answer (score 0):

You're using a character class `[^"\\/"]`; that selects all characters that aren't in the *set* `{", /, \}`. That's probably not what you want.

Instead, try

```
`.*?(\\/|$)`
```

This will match up to the `\/` or the end of string, whichever comes first. Note that the `\/` will be *included* in the match, because Oracle's `regexp_substr` doesn't appear to support *lookahead assertions* yet.

Comment: Thanks, this works better, but now each substrin Ends with \/ how can we avoid this?

Comment: You could slap on a string or regex substitution, for example.

Comment: `replace(regexp_substr(...), '\\/', '')` or something. Though you should really be trying to figure that out yourself...

Comment: ah ok, now i got it. But such a solution costs again performance. Still i am thinking of an way doing it only with regexp...

Comment: Not possible until Oracle properly supports negative lookahead. Also, why are you quibbling about a single `replace`? `regexp_substr` is **much** more expensive.

Comment: Because we have million of rows, of course regexp is slow but in addition with another operation like replace it will get more slower, but we have to test how much...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the words you could just replace the `\/` with `space`:

```
select REPLACE ('word1\/word2\/word3','\/',' ') "changes" FROM dual
```

Or if you want only the first word:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('word1\/word2\/word3', '[^\\^/]+') "changes" FROM dual
```